# Gstreamer Echo cancellation

Tags: c, echo, gstreamer, cancellation

I want to do echo cancellation using gstreamer but i am getting error

`Error: No echo probe with name mp_echo_cancellation1 found.`

I have used below functions
tx side :

```
mp_echo_cancellation = gst_element_factory_make ("webrtcdsp", "echo cancellation");
gst_element_link_many (mp_source, mp_queue,mp_echo_cancellation, mp_level, mp_filter  ,mp_conv , mp_muxer, mp_sink, NULL);
```

rx side :

```
mp_echo_cancellation1 = gst_element_factory_make ("webrtcechoprobe", "echo cancellation1");
gst_element_link_many (mp_source1, mp_queue1,/*rtpdemuxer,*/ mp_decoder1 , mp_conv1, mp_echo_cancellation1,/*mp_resample,*/ mp_sink1, NULL);
```

Please help me out . Thanks in advance

Comment: welcome. I believe you need to use the name of the element of the probe, that is "echo cancellation1". https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/webrtcdsp/webrtcdsp.html?gi-language=c#webrtcdsp:probe